# Background Image and Color collide

Tags: html, css, background

I know its no problem to have a background-image and a background color, but in this case it doesn't work, and I have no clue why.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

```
background: #FFFFFF; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

background-image: url('images/bg_page.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
background-position: right bottom;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, somehow you have to define it combined, then it works:

> ```
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg);
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, #FFFFFF; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #828282); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #828282); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #828282); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
> background: url(images/bg_page.jpg) right bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #828282); /* Standard syntax */
> ```

Comment: exactly, while I was writing you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is used replacing the image, the no shorthand syntax is: `background-image: linear-gradient (#FFFFFF, yellow);` Therefore when you call the image overwrites the previous gradient background.
You can use comma-separated multiple bakgrounds:

```css
.gradient {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png'), linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine :

```css
div{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background: #FFFFFF; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

background-image: url('http://www.mapmonde.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/4-Bahamas12.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
background-position: right bottom; 
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But I think you want this:

```css
div{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background: #FFFFFF; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 
  }
```

```html
<div><img src='http://www.mapmonde.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/4-Bahamas12.jpg' /></div>
```